# Direct Input в Unity

Tags: unity3d, package, visual-studio-2019

День добрый! Столкнулся с проблемой поддержки Direct Input в unity (руль не поддерживается стандартным инпутом). нашел решение на [гитхабе](https://github.com/jamesy012/Direct-Input)
Все бы ничего, но для того, чтобы использовать эту библиотеку мне нужно как то скачать MSVC - C++ Build Tools for VS 2019. Обращался в поддержку майкрософт с тем, чтобы как-нибудь сделать инсталлер или локальный установщик этого пакета. С этой проблемой мне помочь не смогли. Я так же нашел куда закачиваются эти пакеты и нашел vsix файлы, при открытии которых выдает ошибку "Пакет vsix является недействительным...".
Возможно ли как-нибудь завезти этот пакет в установщик игры или нет? А может есть другой способ по установке или местонахождению этого пакета. Или может быть есть другие пакеты с поддержкой Direct Input?

Comment: C++ Build Tools for VS 2019 нужны только для разработки.

Comment: Знаю.. Но почему то без них никак не работает дллка, что прилагается на гите

Comment: Видимо это проблема XY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пересобрав dll файлы directInput заработал и без установки дополнительных библиотек. Нужно пересобрать dll, что в папке cpp с встроенными библиотеками под x32 и x64 и заменить их в проекте в папке plugins

Comment: здесь нет ЛС. И такие ответы являются нарушением правил ресурса. Ты уйдешь с ресурса через неделю или забудешь ответ через месяц и кто-то не решит свою проблему. Есть детали как сделать - пиши сразу в ответе.

Answer (score 2):

Погуглив `Direct Input` сразу с право увидел в сводке из википедии что это **устаревший API**... почему он? откуда вы это взяли? что за хренью вы вообще занимаетесь?

Написал в гугле `unity3d steering wheel input` и увидел множество тем и обсуждений. И то что у unity есть какое-то [свое решения](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@0.2/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.SteeringWheels.SteeringWheel.html) в рамках класса `InputDevice`.

Comment: Все бы ничего.. Но unity никак не взаимодействовала с direct Input. Нам попался такой руль, который работает только с этим инпутом.. InputDevice не определяет оси этого руля. В этом и заключается проблема